# retrieving names of all open pdf files (in evince or otherwise)

Tags: process, scripting, open-files

I constantly have many PDF files open.  These are usually downloaded using chrome and immediately opened using evince.

I sometimes want to persist the state of all my open PDF files, so I could re-open the same group of documents at a later time.

This mostly happens when I need to reboot and what to have the same set of documents re-opened, but sometimes I just want to keep a list of open documents for later.

Is there a way to get the names of all open pdf files, from evince or any other program?
or at least, is there a way of asking evince to re-open the same set of documents after a reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the assumption that the PDFs you are viewing have the extension .pdf, the following could work to get you a list of open PDFs:

```
$ lsof | grep ".pdf$"
```

If you only ever use Evince, see Gilles' similar answer. On my machine (with a few pdfs open) displayed output as follows

```
evince    6267     myuser   14u      REG    252,0   363755    7077955 /tmp/SM.pdf
```

To just get the filenames, we can use `awk`:

```
$ lsof | grep ".pdf$" | awk '{print $9}'
```

or even better,

```
$ lsof | awk '/.pdf$/ {print $9}'
```

We can save these results in a file:

```
$ lsof | awk '/.pdf$/ {print $9}' > openpdfs
```

And later, to restore them:

```
$ xargs -a openpdfs evince
```

To make this happen automatically, you can use whatever mechanisms your desktop environment provides to run the "save" command on exit and the "open" command on login.  A bit more robustness can be added by ensuring that the pdf's returned by `lsof` are being opened by your user.  One advantage of this method is that it should work for any pdf viewer that takes command-line arguments.  One disadvantage is that it depends on file names; however, with a bit of poking, the requirement of knowing the filename extension could probably also be removed.

Answer (score 3):

`lsof` lists the files open by a process. Evince does keep the files open. If you're the only user using evince, under Linux, here's how to see what files it's using:

```
lsof -p $(pgrep -d, -x evince)
```

To automate this, you'll want to keep only the open regular files of the evince process. Here's a script that outputs the file names.

```
lsof -n -d0-9999 -Fpctn |  # parseable output, pid/command/type/name, only open files
sed 's/^p/\np/' |  # split each process into a paragraph
awk -vRS= '/\ncevince\n/ {print}' |  # retain only paragraph(s) with command="evince"
sed 's/^t/\nt/' |  # split each file into a paragraph
awk -vRS= '/^tREG\n/ {print substr($0, 7);}'  # retain only regular files
```

Comment: This no longer works (at least on Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: @Navaro Which part? Does evince no longer keep files open? Or does the second code snippet not output the PDF files? Or does it output other files?

Comment: Sorry, I encountered an issue with the first command because `pidof evince` returns two `ids`

Comment: @Navaro Ah, I see. That was a bug, the command I'd originally posted only worked if there was a single evince process. I've fixed it.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `pgrep -d,` instead of `pidof -d,` ? because `pidof` will match only 'evince', but pgrep will also match the daemon 'evinced'

Comment: @Navaro The `-d` option of `pidof` is a recent addition whereas `pgrep -d` has been around for over a decade. I've added `-x` to exclude `evinced`.